# Change CSS in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to change a `display: none;` to a `display: block`. I'm having troubles and I can't get it to work..

I have to change this:

```
.colorbox #content,.colorbox #nav,.colorbox #header,
.colorbox #service,.colorbox #footer,
.colorbox #disclaimer{display:none}
```

with JQuery to a `display: block`.

Actually I have to change it only in the ID `#footer`.

I tried with:

```
$('.colorbox #content,.colorbox #nav,.colorbox #header, .colorbox #service,.colorbox #footer, .colorbox #disclaimer').css('style', 'display: block !important');
```

or with:

```
$('.colorbox #content,.colorbox #nav,.colorbox #header,.colorbox #service,
 .colorbox #footer,.colorbox #disclaimer').css("display", "block !important");
```

or with:

```
$('#footer').css("display", "block !important");
```

I'm actually loading a css file from a external website.. (HTML also) Is it possible, that I can't access with a single JQuery method to this files to change their values ?

How can I make it ?

Comment: $('#footer').hide(); why not jquery?

Comment: What do you mean why not Jquery ? I'm trying with JQuery.. lol

Comment: Basically In-line styles will have more priority than the id selector. So your code should also works. I am not sure what have you done in a crack pottery way to make this code not working. Please refer this sample fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hxwx2g97/ It is also same like your case.

Comment: Do you have multiple html tag with same ID ?

Comment: As the code you show should work it probably means that your selectors are wrong (please show us the relevant [mcve] html), or you're using jQuery before you've included the jQuery library, or haven't wrapped the jQuery in a `$(document).ready();` or equivalent.

Comment: I'm actually loading a css file from a external website.. (HTML also) Is it possible, that I can't access with a single JQuery method to this files to change their values ?

Comment: You are changing style for element and other CSS have nothing to do with it. Try checking your browser console - maybe you have some typos in your code which causes errors?

Comment: @JCoding I have added four option to do this. You can check my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @ArifulIslam

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#id").css("display", "none");
$("#id").css("display", "block");
```

or

```
$('#id').hide();
$('#id').show();
```

or

```
$("#id").css({display: "none"});
$("#id").css({display: "block"});
```

For class you can give it as:

```
$(".class").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: But this is what I was trying actually? Why is my code not working?

Comment: I don't think you have to pass it as .colorbox #content.. try it directly as $('#content').css("display","block");

Answer (score 1):

You can do it many ways. The following are four easy way:

1. By using only jQuery:

`$("#footer").hide();`

2. Add a class name in CSS and then use addClass with jQuery.

**CSS:**

```
.force_hide{
    display: none !important;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#footer").addClass('force_hide');
```

3. Use `style` instead of `css`:

`$("#footer").style('display', 'none', 'important');`

4. And if you want to use `css` then use it like following:

`$("#footer").css("cssText", "display: none !important;");`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I can't understand your question. Could you please describe a little bit more?

Comment: Though OP's code is a kind of trashy one, still it has to work. There's no errors/no mistakes in his code. Then why it is not working? Adding a class will not answer solve his problem. If his code doesn't works, then yours also wont work in his environment.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy with css in jQuery he used !important, which is only problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

If your #footer has style display: none, than use:

$( "#footer" ).css( "display", "block" )

And remove important tag from css as well.